# Uncaught referenceError on a function

Tags: javascript

I am following a simple tut which will hopefully build out a responsive slider, however it keeps telling me there is an error in the console pointing at a function called `advance()`

Here is the simple html for the slider:

```
<div class="slider">
<div class="slide-viewer">
    <div class="slide-group">
        <div class="slide slide-1">1</div>
        <div class="slide slide-2">2</div>
        <div class="slide slide-3">3</div>
        <div class="slide slide-4">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="slide-buttons"></div>
```

Here is the JS - JQuery has been included before the script file so I know that isn't the issue here but when I click a button it shows me the error in the console:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.slider').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $group = $this.find('.slide-group');
    var $slides = $this.find('.slide');
    var buttonArray = [];
    var currentIndex = 0;
    var timeout;

    function advance(){
        clearTimeout(timeout);

        timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            if (currentIndex < ($slides.length - 1) ){
                move(currentIndex + 1);
            } else {
                move(0);
            }
        }, 4000);
    }

    $.each($slides, function(index){
        var $button = $('<button type="button" class="slide-btn">&bull;</button>');
        if(index === currentIndex) {
            $button.addClass('active');
        }
        $button.on('click', function(){
            move(index);
        }).appendTo('.slide-buttons');
        buttonArray.push($button);
    });

advance();

});

function move(newIndex) {
    var animateLeft, slideLeft;

    advance();

    if ($group.is(':animated') || currentIndex === newIndex) {
        return;
    }

    buttonArray[currentIndex].removeClass('active');
    buttonArray[newIndex].addClass('active');

    if (newIndex > currentIndex) {
        slideLeft = '100%';
        animateLeft = '-100%';
    } else {
        slideLeft = '-100%';
        animateLeft = '100%';
    }

    $slides.eq(newIndex).css( {left: slideLeft, display: 'block'} );
    $group.animate( {left: animateLeft} , function() {
        $slides.eq(currentIndex).css( {display: 'none'} );
        $slides.eq(newIndex).css( {left: 0} );
        $group.css( {left: 0} );
        currentIndex = newIndex;
    });
}
});
```

It tells me the issue is on line 40 of the Js which points towards the second time you see `advance()` in the script. any help would be appreciated as I had to amend the code already as some of it was failing but this has me stumped! Granted Js isn't my strongest language!

Comment: well, advance() call in move function have no access to the advance definitions of the other each loop. Not the same scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that  function `advance(){` is within the foreach scope. It is called within your `move()` function which is not in the same scope.

The easiest would be to move your move method just below your advance function:

```
    function advance(){
        clearTimeout(timeout);

        timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            if (currentIndex < ($slides.length - 1) ){
                move(currentIndex + 1);
            } else {
                move(0);
            }
        }, 4000);
    }

    function move(newIndex) {
    //code for move function here
```